# How to define font color in NSDialogs

Tags: text, nsis, nsdialogs

I can create controls and other elements on a custom dialog, but I cannot seem to apply a desired color to the text in labels.

What I've tried-

```
${NSD_CreateLabel} 25% 15u 25% 15u "${SPEC_CPU_MIN} MHz"
Pop $lCPU_min
CreateFont $R9 "" 9 $R7
SendMessage $lCPU_min ${WM_SETFONT} $R9 0
${NSD_AddStyle} $lCPU_min ${SS_CENTER}

SetCtlColors $lCPU_min "" "0xfff799"
```

This simply fills the rectangle BEHIND the text. Does not affect the font itself. 
Then I tried this -

```
SetCtlColors $lCPU_min "0xfff799" ""
```

This one simply had no effect whatsoever.

Any suggestions?

I'm using NSIS 2.46.

Answer (score 3):

`""` is not documented as a valid background color, try `SetCtlColors $lCPU_min 0xFF0000 0x00FF00` or `SetCtlColors $lCPU_min 0xFF0000 transparent`